# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero when i try show video durations in directory

Tags: python, opencv

Idea: Get duration of all videos in a directory.

Problem: I want to output the duration of all videos in a directory but i get an error and this is my code:

This is original code https://pastebin.com/xnpfwE55

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore
import datetime
import glob
import cv2
init()

w = input(str(Fore.GREEN+"Type path to dir: ")) # path of directory
b = print(str(glob.glob(w+"*"))) # Adds a directory and reads files from there
print(b)
# create video capture object
data = cv2.VideoCapture(str(b))

# count the number of frames
frames = data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
fps = int(data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

# calculate dusration of the video
seconds = int(frames / fps)
video_time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))
print("duration in seconds:", seconds)
print("video time:", video_time)
```

What should I do?

Output:

```
[gooder@GOD ffmpeg]$ python untitled2.py 
Type path to dir: /home/gooder/Desktop/ffmpeg/videos/
['/home/gooder/Desktop/ffmpeg/videos/ou1t.mp4', '/home/gooder/Desktop/ffmpeg/videos/out.mp4', '/home/gooder/Desktop/ffmpeg/videos/Halloween.Kills.2021.DUB.HDRip.x264.mkv']
None
[ WARN:0@1.851] global /build/opencv/src/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1127) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: no element "None"
[ WARN:0@1.851] global /build/opencv/src/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ERROR:0@2.770] global /build/opencv/src/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (164) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.5) /build/opencv/src/opencv-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): None in function 'icvExtractPattern'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gooder/Desktop/ffmpeg/untitled2.py", line 19, in <module>
    seconds = int(frames / fps)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: not familiar with cv2, but `data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)` may for some reason be > 0 but < 1 so `int(data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))` will return zero.

Comment: `b` is None - the result of `print()`, rather than anything related to the files on your disk.    `cv2.VideoCapture(str(b))` therefore failed to work (and `cv2` tends to require you to explicitly check return values, rather than raising exceptions), so everything you did with its result is meaningless.

Comment: @jasonharper So... can you tell me how i can fix this?

Comment: if fps is 0, you simply can't calculate. check for fps being 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confused code in this line:

```py
b = print(str(glob.glob(w+"*"))) # Adds a directory and reads files from there
```

You glob the contents of the directory you entered in the variable `w`, convert that list to a string, `print` that string to standard output and then assign `None` to `b`, because `print` writes its arguments to standard output (or some other stream) and doesn't return anything.

It has already been pointed out in the comments that calling `print` in this way won't do what you want here. The first step would therefore be to get rid of it:

```py
b = str(glob.glob(w+"*")) # Adds a directory and reads files from there
print(b)
```

However that's not enough, because `b` won't be a filename, it will be the result of converting a list of filenames to a string. Attempting to open a file whose name is the value of `b` will still fail.

`glob.glob` returns a list, with each item in the list being a file that matched the pattern given. You need to loop through this list and then run the rest of your code once for each item in the list:

```py
for b in glob.glob(w+"*"): # Adds a directory and reads files from there
    print(b)

    # create video capture object
    data = cv2.VideoCapture(b)

    # remaining lines also indented, but omitted here for brevity
```

Each time through the loop, `b` should be the name of one of the files in the directory you entered.

Finally, in case `cv2` can't read the FPS for a video file for whatever reason, I would recommend not attempting to calculate the duration of the video.  Replace the code at the bottom of your loop with something like the following:

```py
    if fps == 0:
        print("Could not read an FPS value, unable to calculate duration of video")
    else:
        # calculate duration as normal...
```